# Should spellcasting services be limited in E6? How?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, economy, e6

Pathfinder E6 limits PC level to 6th to disallow the players from using level 4+ spells. This means, for example, that resurrection of a fallen friend is not what PCs can normally do, nor can they teleport, etc.

However, there is one simple way to access high-level magic in E6: spellcasting services, which cost Caster Level*Spell Level*10 GP. This always 2.5 times cheaper than a scroll which costs CL*Spell Level*25 GP. This somewhere around 280 GP for a 4th level spell, and, granted that you find a settlement big enough, you don't need to work hard to find it on sale. For a 5th level spell, service cost is somewhat close to 450 GP, while a scroll of the same level costs 1125 GP.

Of course, to use, say Reincarnate, PCs need 1000 more GP to pay for material components, and they would likely also want two uses of Restoration, each worth 1000 GP, to get rid of negative levels, each cast also costing 280 GP for spellcasting service... But hey, death is no longer permanent for them.

Overall, this means that reincarnating a dead adventurer costs 3000+840=3840 GP, which is a lot, but certainly not completely unavailable for E6 characters.

In my opinion, this *can* kinda break the very idea of E6 if allowed to be used as by RAW.

**Can it kill a E6 game? Should I prevent this as a game master? If yes, how? Should I limit the availability of such services? Should I completely scrap those rules?**

I expect answers from people who have used spellcasting service rules in their Pathfinder E6 games, or have made a deliberate decision not to use them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mortal spellcasters, the kind typically found in towns selling services, should be restricted to 6th level the same as PCs. There simply shouldn’t *be anyone* high enough level just selling magic like that.

Higher-level spells in E6 is intended to be a matter of significant effort and investment. Incantations, carefully controlled by DM, or side-quests to find powerful monsters willing to cast the spell, are the intended ways to get higher-level effects. The latter might be willing to “sell” the service, but most of the time they are likely to be more interested in payment in favors and quests, not money. And even when they want money, they want legendary amounts of it—not the typical business cost of them.

Answer (score 5):

Rules As Written, spellcasting services are already limited in Pathfinder E6.
On Page 11 of http://p6codex.com/AbridgedP6CodexV0p2.pdf, it says:

> The available spells for PCs and NPCs are all those
>   normally obtainable by a 6th level character: Cleric,
>   Druid, and Sorcerer/ Wizard spells of 3rd level or lower...

If you really do want answers from people who have used spellcasting services rules to access spells above third level, I recommend that you rephrase your question to make it clear you understand that this would be a house rule.